# TS2345: Argument of type '() => in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I resolve this :

```
TS2345: Argument of type '() => Observable<R | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void | Subscribable<never> | Subscribable<R> | PromiseLike<R> | InteropObservable<R>'.   Type 'Observable<R | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'void | Subscribable<never> | Subscribable<R> | PromiseLike<R> | InteropObservable<R>'.     Type 'Observable<R | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'InteropObservable<R>'.       Property '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type 'Observable<R| undefined>
```

This comes from this :

```
  public open<T, D, R>(
    templateOrComponentRef: TemplateRef<T> | ComponentType<T>,
    config: MatDialogConfig<D>,
  ): Observable<R> {
    return defer<R>(() => {
      const ref = this.create<T, D, R>(templateOrComponentRef, config);
      return ref.afterClosed();
    });
  }
```

precisly from the `() => {`

Where :

```
  public create<T, D, R>(
    templateOrComponentRef: TemplateRef<T> | ComponentType<T>,
    config: MatDialogConfig<D>,
  ): MatDialogRef<T, R> {
    return this.dialog.open<T, D>(templateOrComponentRef, config);
  }
```

Using Angular `6.1.3`

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=TS2345%3A+Argument+of+type+is+not+assignable+to+parameter+of+type

Comment: At first glance, it looks like the return type of the `ref.afterClosed()` doesn't match the expected type of `'() => void | Subscribable<never> | Subscribable<R> | PromiseLike<R> | InteropObservable<R>'`

Comment: You shouldn't return something that could be  `void` or `Subscribable<never>` or `Subscribable<R>`, or `PromiseLike<R>`, or `InteropObservable<R>` instead you should return a result that could be of type `Observable<R>` or `Observable<undefined>`. That's what the error message means. How you resolve it depens on your application, I guess.

Comment: Thanks but the error is not explicit at all, I don't see what's wrong with my implementation at all. (and yes I googled and got to github before, not helping here)

Comment: `Thanks but the error is not explicit at all` I've never seen it before and it was pretty clear to me. `I don't see what's wrong with my implementation at all` your function returns one types of responses. They do not match the expected, either It needs to be another kinds of responses or you need to convert them somehow. In Java it'd be the equivalent to trying to pass something `List<T>` to a method that takes `Set<T>` or an otherwise incompatible type.

Comment: Can you past the code of the afterClosed function ?

Comment: AfterClose is a function of the type MatDialogRef : `afterClosed(): Observable<R | undefined>;`

Comment: `afterClosed()` returns `Observable<R | undefined>`, and your `open<T, D, R>()` method is defined to return `Observable<R>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution :

```
  public open<T, D, R>(
    templateOrComponentRef: TemplateRef<T> | ComponentType<T>,
    config: MatDialogConfig<D>,
  ): Observable<R | undefined> {
    const ref = this.create<T, D, R>(templateOrComponentRef, config);
    return ref.afterClosed();
  }
```

As you can see I removed `defer()` to match the return type. Since only one dialog should be open at a time this should be ok.